# MongoDB installation is not showing the bin directory

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have installed MongoDB in my PC. However, I find no trace of the bin folder inside the MongoDB/Server/6.0 folder.

I have installed MongoDB using the file 'mongodb-windows-x86_64-6.0.4-signed' on my computer having the OS 'Microsoft Windows 10 Home' and 'x64'. However, when I go through the installation directory i.e E:/MongoDB there seems to be some error. MongoDB/Server/6.0 does not contain any folder with the name 'bin'. It contains only 2 folders viz a viz 'data' and 'log'. The issue seems to be confirmed when I run the command 'mongo' in the command prompt it returns that 'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'. Although I haven't added the .exe to the PATH variable yet I sense that the installation itself isn't proper. I have also tried multiple reinstallations and repair. As of now I only seek help to complete the proper installation

Comment: `MongoDB/Server/6.0 does not contain any folder with the name 'bin'. It contains only 2 folders viz a viz 'data' and 'log'.` - you've entered in the folder with your db files, not where mongo binaries are placed

Comment: Isn't the data folder located as MongoDB/Server/6.0/data. I am inside MongoDB/Server/6.0 . I am expecting a folder bin here. I can't get as to why I should be inside the folder with the db files.

Comment: I am not sure whether installer creates a `bin` folder. Did you find the `.exe` files? Or are you looking just for `mongo.exe` shell?

Comment: `bin` it's a folder with server binaries. `data` is a folder with database files created when you have launched your binaries. Normally these are completely different folders. But where they're located depends on what configuration you used during installing

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I don't think there is any trace of .exe files. I have looked inside entirely. And I am not looking for mongosh. I have downloaded it separately. Btw at the time of this reply I am giving another try with the reinstallation.